# Possible to run a Lightning node on same computer as Bitcoin Core node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, full-node

I have a Windows 10 laptop that is running a full Bitcoin node using Bitcoin Core. Is it possible to also run a Lightning node on the same laptop simultaneously with the Bitcoin node?

Answer (score 2):

Yes but some lightning implementations are not running on windows. Lightning needs hardly any hardware but requires to talk to a Bitcoin node (local or remote) anyway.

Comment: Thanks Rene - is there a website or instructions online that you know of that would walk me through exactly what I need to do to get the Lightning node running? I don't want anything I do to mess up my Bitcoin node.

Comment: I think lnd runs on windows their installation guide says exactly how to download, compile, install lnd and fire it up with bitcoind as its backend. you might have to open a communication channel via bitcoin.conf but that is also described on their site: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md

Comment: Actually, at least the three big implementations do all run fine on Windows. OP might want to consult this guide for a very simple installation of bitcoind and lnd with nice UI on Windows: https://medium.com/lightning-power-users/windows-macos-lightning-network-284bd5034340